# Increment decrement quantity with Angular form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, increment

I'm trying to implement an increment/decrement function on my form for a list of products. The idea is to be able to add products to cart with live update of the cart through products quantity.

I came across this code sample from Angular docs which I think could do the trick.
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

What I'm expecting is when I click on product for the first time it adds product to form params then increment each time I tap on product (Another solution would be to style html5 number field though but still issue with form fields logic)

[image]

`"order": [{"product_id": "2", "quantity": "10"}, {"product_id": "5", "quantity": "12"}]`

My problem is:
- I can't get form right (product_id * quantity) using formData
- Increment quantity function is way off

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/lCZUXpTeJqGkOllXaS2t?p=preview

```
<form ng-submit="processForm()">
  <pre>{{ formData }}</pre>

    <ul ng-repeat="product in filtered = (products | orderBy:['name'] | filter:q)">
      <li>{{ product.name }}
         <a ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" ng-model="formData.products">Increment - count: {{count}}
          <input type="number" ng-model="formData.{{product.id}}" />
     </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: can you provide a plunker or give us more detail about what is your problem?

Comment: @wickY26 the problem is that current form is way off compared to the mockup. Will try to provide plunker example a bit later

Comment: @wickY26 Added Plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/lCZUXpTeJqGkOllXaS2t?p=preview

Comment: do you want to set ng model like formdata[product.id] ?

Comment: @wickY26 forms params should look like [{product_id: 2, quantity: 3}, {product_id: 5, quantity: 12}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only set quantity by binding `ng-model` but you are looking to set an full object `{product_id: x, quantity: y}`...

so use ng-change instead of ng-model to set formData...

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="quantity" placeholder="product_{{product.id}}" 
ng-change="changeQuantity($index, product.id, quantity)">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.changeQuantity =function (index, productId, quantity) {
   $scope.formData[index] = {product_id: productId, quantity: quantity};
};
```

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1GEsL5IooR8MROuiAoc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @wickY26 any idea to complete remove product from the array when quantity is nil or 0 (for example when user inputs quantity then decides to remove product)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate. While converting to coffee script it raises error when changing quantity. `Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.formData.push({
          product_id: productId,
          quantity: quantity
        })')`